# TypeScript. При выполнении tsc ошибка missing script: tsc

Tags: typescript

app.ts

```
var el = this.document.getElementById("content");

class User{
    name : string;
    age : number;
    constructor(_name:string, _age: number){

        this.name = _name;
        this.age = _age;
    }
}
var tom : User = new User("Том", 29);
el.innerHTML="Имя: " + tom.name + " возраст: " + tom
```

package.json

```
{
  "author": "user",
  "name": "Project_01",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Generated with typescript.java",
}
```

При команде

```
npm run tsc app.ts
```

Получаю

```
npm ERR! missing script: tsc
```

ОС: Windows 10
tsc -v: 6.4.1

Comment: npm run - запускает скрипты описанные в секции `scripts` в package.json, так как у тебя такой секции вообще нет - ты и получаешь ошибку. Можешь попробовать запускать tsc без `npm run`, сразу: `tsc app.ts`

Comment: tsc - такая команда не существует. По этому пути тоже ничего нет %AppData%\npm\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsc --version

Comment: Так может быть у тебя он просто и не установлен? :-)

Comment: ну эта же команда как-то работает npm run tsc -v

Comment: а если просто `tsc -v` запускаешь? Как установлен tsc? из какой папки ты его пробуешь запустить?

Comment: действительно не установлен. Выполнил npm install -g typescript. Заработало

Comment: Кстати, попробуй выполнить просто `npm -v` :)

Comment: вопрос решён. см. комментарий выше

Comment: Я к тому, что вывод бы совпал с тем, что у тебя был при `npm run tsc -v`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выполнить npm install -g typescript